# Is the set of available RPC calls dependant on the connected node?

Tags: tezos-client, rpc

When I am connected to `rpcalpha.tzbeta.net` through `tezos-client -l -A rpcalpha.tzbeta.net -S -P 443 config update` I can succesfully call `tezos-client activate account alice with <path_to_downloaded_json>`.

But when I connect to my own node an run the same command, I get:

```
% tezos-client activate account alice with <path_to_downloaded_json>                                                                                                                     ~ tezos-node
Error:
  Unrecognized command.
  Try using the man command to get more information.

Usage:
```

My '~/.tezos-client/config' content when connected to my own node is

```
{
    "base_dir": "/home/troels/.tezos-client",
    "node_addr": "127.0.0.1",
    "node_port": 9999
}
```

Comment: Can you check that your node is synchronized? Try running `tezos-client get timestamp`.

Comment: I can confirm that my own node is **not** syncronized. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes. Some of the commands in tezos-client are defined by the protocol. If your node is not synchronized, then it is probably running a bare bones protocol, that lack even basic commands like `get balance for`. Are you just testing the node, or do you want to get the balance for a real account on the chain?

Comment: If the latter, you need to synchronize to get the full state of the block chain and the latest protocol. If the former, you can check out sandbox mode: http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/sandbox.html

Comment: For now I am just running a node on the Carthage test net. But I would like a real (and syncronized) node and real account up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a subset of the RPCs exposed by the node is provided by the protocol. Thus, depending on the node that you connect to and the protocol that it is running, some RPCs will be available or not. The documentation [gives a note on this](http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtouse.html#client):

> Beware that the commands available on the client depend on the
> specific protocol run by the node. For instance, get timestamp isn’t
> available when the node runs the genesis protocol, which may happen
> for a few minutes when launching a node for the first time.

Here it talks about `tezos-client` commands, but these are often just wrappers around calls to the node RPCs, a subset of which are defined by the protocol.

Comment: So to be absolutely clear: The set of available RPC calls will change as the node is syncing and its local version of the blockchain gets longer? Without further configurations from the node administrator?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.